# Do I need to stop Log backups when I stop data sync on AOAG?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017

I was curious about this specific topic.

If I stop data sync to alter primary without affecting secondaries, do I need to stop log backup jobs? does a log backup during the stop data sync would mess up any LSN and make it impossible to restore data sync again?

Edit.

so ,I have a database, part of AOAG between 2 servers. if I hit "stop data sync" secondary will stop receiving information from primary.

in this meantime, what happens if I do a "backup log" ini the primary database? will it break the AOAG connection when I "resume data sync"?
will LSN be different?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, would you please update it with an example or change the wording?

Comment: Thanks @SeanGallardy-MostlyRetired I tried to word better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so ,I have a database, part of AOAG between 2 servers. if I hit "stop data sync" secondary will stop receiving information from primary.

If you do this on the primary database (suspend) then it'll suspend for *all* secondary database replicas. If you do this on a secondary database, it'll just suspend for that secondary replica.

While any replicas are suspended, the log on the primary will grow as the primary will be required to hold the log from the oldest outstanding point for any replica.

> in this meantime, what happens if I do a "backup log" ini the primary database? will it break the AOAG connection when I "resume data sync"? will LSN be different?

No, you'll be fine. The log will be backed up as per usual and if you resume data movement to the secondary replica, it will resume without issue. It will most likely cause extra reads of the log and some churning of the log pool on the primary. This could cause other issues down the line but won't break backup chains, primary, or secondary replicas just by suspending and taking a backup then resuming.

Comment: Definitely keep your log backups running.  They won't clean out the .ldf file(s), but they will let you recover from disasters; and disasters are significantly more disastrous when your secondaries aren't synced.